# materialized css HTML5 Range slider doesn't show thumb

Tags: css, materialize

I use Materialize: 1.0.0 , no thumb showing on html5 range

If I use Materialize: 0.100.2 and 0.97.3, both works fine do show thumb number.

I can not down-grade to 0.100.2 and 0.97.3, 
Because all my other code use,instance M, 
for example, M.Tab.... M.xxx....(0.100.2 and 0.97.3 NOT support M.tab..)

We must fix 1.0.0 range thumb issue, but how?

Comment: When you say 'no thumb' - what do you mean? The docs seem to be working fine, and they use 1.0.0 https://materializecss.com/range.html. Can you link to project/create codepen?

Answer (score 1):

Working code:

depends what version you use:

case 1:

For v1.0.0 failed to show range thrumb, must M.Range.init("input[type=range]")

```
                //for materializ-css v1.0.0 without this range will failed to show thrumb 
                // for materializ-css v0.100.2 and 0.97.3 works fine without(can NOT use) M.range.init
                var array_of_dom_elements = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=range]");
                M.Range.init(array_of_dom_elements);
```

case 2:

For v0.100.2 and v0.97.3 works without (and can NOT use) M.Range.init

v0.100.2 and v0.97.3 do not support M.xxx instance style

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that will works because the materialize.js  tag is included immediately **before the closing body tag**. If I move it to the document head, the thumb doesn't work anymore.

read more at https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize/issues/6036